CH32V003 Timer2 DMA WS2812 control
I'm trying to implement DMA-based control of ws2812 led. So idea was to put values of positive time periods to 24 bytes and use that values for compare register. If I understand correctly, each time when timer reaches value of ATRLR, it triggers DMA request update. And DMA controller should increment address and put value from memory to periphereal address. But for some reason each time I call start_output, the only thing I get is single pulse of 16us. I'm using ch32v003fun framework
main.c
#include <ch32v003fun.h>
#include <sys_tick.h>
#include <soft_uart.h>
#include <status_led.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

uint8_t green = 0;
uint8_t blue = 0;

int main(void){
    SystemInit();
    funGpioInitAll();
    soft_uart_init(SOFT_UART_TX);
    Delay_Ms(100);
    init_status_led(PC1);
    set_color(255, 255, 0);

    soft_uart_tx_str("Hello world\n");

    bool flag = false;
    uint8_t red = 0;
    uint32_t next_led_update_time_ticks = SysTick->CNT + Ticks_from_Ms(1000);
    while(1){
        if(SysTick->CNT >= next_led_update_time_ticks){
            red = flag ?  255 : 0;
            flag = flag ^ 1;
            set_color(red, green, blue);
            next_led_update_time_ticks = SysTick->CNT + Ticks_from_Ms(1000);
        }
    };
}

status_led.c
#include "status_led.h"
#include <ch32v003fun.h>
#include <sys_tick.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <soft_uart.h>

#define BITS_CNT 24
#define BH 42
#define BL 15

static uint8_t pixel_bits[BITS_CNT] = {
    BL, BL, BL, BL, BL, BL, BL, BH,
    BL, BL, BL, BL, BL, BL, BL, BH,
    BL, BL, BL, BL, BL, BL, BL, BH
};

uint8_t bit_index;
uint32_t color;

void start_output() {
    soft_uart_tx_str("start output\n");
    bit_index = 0;  // Reset bit index

    TIM2->CH1CVR = 0;  // Clear Compare Register initially
    TIM2->SWEVGR |= TIM_UG;  // Generate an update event to load new prescaler value

    // Force output low initially
    TIM2->CHCTLR1 &= ~TIM_OC1M;  // Clear output compare mode bits for CH1
    TIM2->CHCTLR1 |= TIM_ForcedAction_InActive;  // Force output inactive

    // Configure DMA for pixel_bits transfer
    DMA1_Channel2->CFGR &= ~DMA_CFG5_EN;  // Disable DMA channel before configuration

    DMA1_Channel2->PADDR = (uint32_t)&TIM2->CH1CVR;  // Peripheral address (16-bit register)
    DMA1_Channel2->MADDR = (uint32_t)pixel_bits;  // Memory address
    DMA1_Channel2->CNTR = BITS_CNT;  // Number of data items to transfer

    DMA1_Channel2->CFGR = DMA_CFG5_MINC |   // Enable memory increment
                          DMA_CFG5_DIR |    // Memory to Peripheral
                          DMA_CFG5_PSIZE_0 |  // Peripheral size 8 bits
                          DMA_CFG5_MSIZE_0 |  // Memory size 8 bits
                          DMA_Priority_High;  // High priority for DMA

    DMA1_Channel2->CFGR |= DMA_CFG5_EN;  // Enable DMA channel

    // Enable Update DMA request
    TIM2->DMAINTENR |= TIM_UDE;

    // Start the timer
    TIM2->CTLR1 |= TIM_CEN;  // Enable Timer2
    __NOP();  // Small delay to ensure low state is applied

    // Set PWM Mode 1
    TIM2->CHCTLR1 &= ~TIM_OC1M;  // Clear output compare mode bits for CH1
    TIM2->CHCTLR1 |= TIM_OCMode_PWM1;  // Set PWM Mode 1
    TIM2->CHCTLR1 |= TIM_OC1PE;  // Enable Preload for CH1
    TIM2->CCER |= TIM_CC1E;  // Enable Output for CH1
    soft_uart_tx_str("start ouptut end\n");
}

void stop_output() {
    soft_uart_tx_str("stop output\n");
    TIM2->DMAINTENR &= ~(TIM_UDE);  // Disable Update DMA request
    TIM2->CCER &= ~TIM_CC1E;  // Disable Output for CH1 to force low
    TIM2->CTLR1 &= ~(TIM_CEN);  // Disable Timer2
    DMA1_Channel2->CFGR &= ~DMA_CFG5_EN;  // Disable DMA channel
    soft_uart_tx_str("stop ouptut end\n");
}

void init_status_led(uint8_t pin) {
    soft_uart_tx_str("init led start\n");
    funPinMode(pin, GPIO_Speed_10MHz | GPIO_CNF_OUT_PP_AF);  // Configure pin as Alternate Function
    __asm volatile("csrw 0x7C0, %0" : : "r"(1<<13));

    AFIO->PCFR1 |= AFIO_PCFR1_TIM2_REMAP_FULLREMAP;  // Set full remap mode
    RCC->APB1PCENR |= RCC_APB1Periph_TIM2;  // Enable timer clock
    RCC->AHBPCENR |= RCC_AHBPeriph_DMA1;  // Enable DMA clock

    TIM2->PSC = 0;  // Set prescaler (internal ticks per one timer tick)
    TIM2->ATRLR = 62;  // Max timer ticks to overflow
    soft_uart_tx_str("init led end\n");
}

void set_color(uint8_t red, uint8_t green, uint8_t blue) {
    for (uint8_t color_index = 0; color_index < 3; color_index++) {
        uint8_t _color = 0;
        switch (color_index) {
            case 0:
                _color = blue;
                break;
            case 1:
                _color = red;
                break;
            case 2:
                _color = green;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        for (uint8_t i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            pixel_bits[color_index * 8 + i] = (_color & (1 << (7 - i))) ? BH : BL;
        }
    }
    start_output();  // Start DMA-based output
}

Please, help me to understand where problem is, thanks in advance
